# How to align child widgets of Card Widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Unable to align left to child widgets of Card  Widgets in flutter,.

```
  Widget buildProductsItem(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Card(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Image.asset("icons/apple_icon.jpg"),
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
          ),
          Text(products[index],
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepOrange, fontSize: 30.0),
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

IN above code child of Card `Widget` align in Centre ,how to align to left side, I used `Container` for that but its not working container not moved to left.

Comment: can you please show your code?

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: @Sami Kanafani do you have any idea.